# Can Android Integer resources be used in switch statements?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a "numeric.xml" file in my project's "values" directory that holds most of the project's integer constants.  I would like to use some of those constants in a switch statement, but Eclipse/Java does not like that because it does not consider "resources.getInteger(R.integer.INTEGER_NAME)" to be a constant.  Is there some way to get the compiler and/or Eclipse to see that it is a constant, or do I just need to live with if/else chains?

Edit: I tried doing "final int INTEGER_NAME = resources.getInteger(R.integer.INTEGER_NAME)" and using INTEGER_NAME in the case statement, but that didn't work either.

Comment: i tryed these and it worked 
`Resources r = getResources();
  int i = r.getInteger(R.integer.lol);
  switch (i) {
  case 1:
   Log.d("lol", "hehehe0");
   break;

  default:
   break;
  }`

Comment: @subspider - OP is asking about using the resut of `r.getInteger(...)` as a **case** value, not as the `switch` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, your integer resource values are not constants. How is the compiler supposed to know the value for each case? There's always the possibility of retrieving different values for different configurations. (You could, for instance, have a `values-land` resource folder with different values for landscape.) Or you could just change the values in the xml file.

If they are truly constants, define them in code. The only other alternative I can see is to create a dispatch table of Runnable (or Callable) objects, one for each branch of the switch, and retrieve the appropriate one based on the value retrieved from the resources.

Comment: Ted, thanks for that answer.  I hope you don't mind if I ask you a Java newbie question.  Is there a clean way of defining constants in Java such that they are defined in one place but can be seen by multiple unrelated classes?

Comment: @Jim Clay yes you place in class that extends from Application and declare variable as static hope it helped but if it is constant is better using xml resorces just if it is complex type i would use static

Comment: @Jim - I use interfaces a lot for that. You can define an interface as just a collection of field values. By the language spec, these are implicitly final and static.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I'd recommend against using an Interface for constants, use a Constants class instead, and possibly a [static import](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Comment: @dave.c - What I like about using interfaces is that I can simply declare a class to implement the interface and all the constant names are then part of the class's name space. Could you elaborate on why an interface is not a good idea?

Comment: @Ted Hopp by (ab)using an Interface for constants you are polluting the public API of your class with all the constants in the Interface.  This is bad practice, and you can achieve the same effect of having the constants in the class namespace by using a static import on the constants class.  Have a look at the link I posted, or read Effective Java, item 17.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `resources.getInteger(R.integer.INTEGER_NAME)` is no more a constant than `resources.getString(R.string.STRING_NAME)`: its a lookup, so you're not really going to be able to use them in a case statement. You'll have to live with the if/else chain.

Answer (score 0):

i tryed these and it worked

```
Resources r = getResources(); 
int i = r.getInteger(R.integer.lol); 
switch (i) { 
    case 1: 
        Log.d("lol", "hehehe0"); 
        break; 
    default: 
        break; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could see that working, but that isn't quite what I want.  I want to replace the "case 1" with "case r.getInteger...".

Comment: OP is asking about using the resut of `r.getInteger(...)` as a `case` value, not as the `switch` parameter.

Comment: @Jim Clay can i know why you want to do these or in what context?

Comment: I have a function that takes some input parameters that tell it to leave certain booleans alone, set them to true, or set them to false.  In a C/C++ program I would handle something like that with an enum and a switch.  Obviously with only three possibilities an if/else chain isn't a big deal, but I was curious to see if there was a solution.